# access jquery element after append function

Tags: jquery

I use append function in order do add some div into another element

```
('#test-append').append("<div class='new_div'><b>some text</b></div>")
```

everything is going fine and I can see the added div,`but I also need after that to access the div selector in order to do something with this div for example to hide it
so i use the folowing

```
$('.new_div').click(function(){
            do somthing here
        });
```

but it is not working even if I just use simple alert('hi') call. It seems like jquery doesn't recognize the append class (I also tried it with Id and I get the same result)

I will appreciate some help on this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

before jquery 1.7 you needed to use live() or delegate() to bind events to elements ignoring whether they existed at the time of binding or not.

since jquery 1.7, you can use

```
$('root-element').on('click', 'selector', function () { do it })
```

above is edited as per jaspers comments

Comment: If jQuery 1.7 is included then `.click(...)` maps to `.on('click', ...)`

Comment: `bind()` does not use event delegation so it will only bind to elements that are currently in the DOM when the binding takes place. And you are using `.on()` just like `.bind()` so that won't delegate the event either, to use `.on()` it's got to be in this format: `$('root-element').on('click', 'selector', function () { do it })`.

Comment: somebody delete this lousy answer...@jasper, thanks, perhaps you should post that comment as the answer?

Comment: the only good thing i can do is to provide the link i only skimmed and jasper read: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 4):

You could append the element, then select it as it will be a child element of the original selection:

```
$('#test-append').append("<div class='new_div'><b>some text</b></div>").children('.new_div').click(...);
```

Or you could use `.appendTo()` which appends the element(s) but also keeps them selected:

```
$("<div class='new_div'><b>some text</b></div>").appendTo('#test-append').click(...);
```

Or as others have stated you can save a reference to the element in a variable and then use that variable at a later time to manipulate the element:

```
var $element = $("<div class='new_div'><b>some text</b></div>").appendTo('#test-append');
$element.click(...);//but you could have just chained the call like the previous example
```

Comment: After several hours of debugging I didn't spot something so simple as ".appendTo() which appends the element(s) but also keeps them selected". Jasper you really saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not recommended method... but it works (jQuery 2.1.3)

```
$('.current_element').append("<div class='future_element'><b>some text</b></div>").find('.future_element').click(function(){
    console.log('you can see me if you click appended element');
});
```

and version when we append element on click

```
$('.current_element').click(function(){
    $('body').append("<div class='future_element'>anything</div>");
    $('.future_element').click(function(){
        $(this).text('do something with appended element'); //for example
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably declare the div first then use append to.

```
var newDiv=$("<div class='new_div'><b>some text</b></div>");

newDiv.appendto('#test-append');

newDiv.click(function(){ do somthing here });
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
$("#test-append").on("event","#test-append .new_div", functoin(){
    //do something 
   });
```